# Picture Box image source is it possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

Hi I want to set dynamic path to my picture box in winforms. Is it possible to do like this

my image is here some thing like

http://www.indianorphanages.net/images/india-political-map.gif

now I want to bind it to picture box (winforms)

Is it possible?

Comment: Does that matter, the ImageLocation property will accept an image on the local disk or on the web.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation =
                "http://www.indianorphanages.net/images/india-political-map.gif";
```

Comment: It takes some time to load it.

Answer (score 3):

To update a picture box from a file you can use the `Load` method:

```
pictureBox.Load(filename);
```

From the help:

> Load(String) Sets the ImageLocation to the specified URL and displays the image indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the ImageLocation property like this:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.indianorphanages.net/images/india-political-map.gif";
```